# Azure Devops and Azure Databricks authentication tokens

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks, azure-authentication

Recently I've been developing a python package `install_databricks_packages` which contacts the Databricks APIs (using `requests`, not the CLI) in order to install packages on Databricks Clusters. This package is used in release pipelines, where one can add a bash script which uses `install_databricks_packages` as a cli to install the needed packages on  one or more clusters.

The problem is that during development I realized I need two different tokens in order to make `install_databricks_packages` work with packages hosted on our private Azure Artifacts repository, where we host some internally developed packages. The first token is a Databricks PAT which is needed to authorize the API call, the second one is a DevOps PAT needed when calling the `/api/2.0/libraries/install` API in order to install a package. Basically, I need to call the API like this

```
import requests

data = {"cluster_id": 123,
        "libraries": [
            {"pypi": {
                 "package": "private_package==1.0.0",
                 "repo": "https://<devops-token>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<company>/pypi/simple/"
            }}
        ]}

requests.post(https://<host>/api/2.0/libraries/install, auth=('token', <databricks-token>))
```

I generated the two tokens with my user and saved them on Azure KeyVault as two different secrets, which can then be fetched in any release pipeline using the Azure KeyVault task.

I was wondering whether this is the only course of action. Having two PAT which are connected to a specific user and have expiration dates, thus have to be manually managed, is cumbersome. I couldn't find a better solution looking online, so any advice is welcome!

Comment: For the devops token, you could use System.AccessToken instead, you need to grant build service account for the package.